# Azure elastic database pool storage limit briefly drops to zero

Tags: azure, database, azure-sql

Yesterday and today I my azure web app experienced bunch of timeouts and 502's for few minutes. While investigating I found out that database storage limit and storage used dropped to zero at that time. Application (one app, many databases) was not restarted.

In short, this happened:
[image]

Server usage was low (that huge spike was me and few dozen MiB of sql script)
[image]

Can this be my fault or is it on hosting side?
Can I protect my database from such problem?
Would virtual machine be more stable?

Comment: I'm not aware of anyway a user can alter the available DTU other than scaling the SQL instance. During a scale event it could drop whist teh DB is being resized, did anyone scale the DB? Other than that I think it may be a question for Azure support.

Answer (score 0):

Azure provides a link that can be used to help troubleshoot 502 errors.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-troubleshoot-http-502-http-503

As per that doc 502 errors are often caused by the following:

-requests taking a long time
-application using high memory/CPU
-application crashing due to an exception.

You can also check the Resource Health tab in the Portal after clicking on your webapp to see if there were any platform issues detected during this time. Else, as Sam mentioned in the comment section you likely would need to contact Azure Support to have the investigate the backed. If this is not a reoccurring issue I suggest simply reviewing the doc provided and monitoring your app.